# Find function of regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

Hi All I just started regex  and executed the sample code

```
package practice;

import java.util.regex.*;

public class Regexpr2 {



    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("Java 7 naya hai") ;
        Matcher match = pat.matcher("Java");
        System.out.println("Here I am ------------>");
        if (match.find())
            System.out.println("got it using find method---------");
        else 
            System.out.println("didnt got");

    }
}
```

But the Output I not what I expected

```
enter code here
```

output:

Here I am ------------>
didnt got

Can Someone explain why is "else" Statement is getting excuted

Comment: Please make sure your question is formatted correctly before posting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern needs to be a sub sequence of the matching `String` rather than the other way round

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Java");
```

Note: you don't need to use regular expressions since youre using simple `Strings`

```
if ("Java 7 naya hai".contains("Java")) {
  ...
}
```